# How do I PERMANENTLY delete old email addresses in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to know how to PERMANENTLY delete old email addresses in the Thunderbird email program. When I delete them, and then restart Thunderbird, all of the deleted email addresses are restored. Very frustrating. Thank you.

Comment: Deleting them from where, the address book?

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the whole profile is not an issue, then you can clear it by deleting the profile located in a folder inside (/home/user/.thunderbird) on linux. On Windows, It can be found in (%APPDATA%/Roaming/Thunderbird)

I suggest cutting the things inside and backing them up somewhere, just in case a rollback is needed.